# HTTPD (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address

Tags: redhat, httpd

My config:

```
    IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf


Listen 172.158.50.122:443
Listen 172.158.50.9:443

Listen 172.158.50.9:7777
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
TraceEnable off
<Directory /icons>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName xxxx.gogo.in

  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile conf/xxxx_gogo_in.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/xxxx_gogo_in.key
  SSLCACertificateFile conf/xxxx_gogo_in.crt

  RedirectMatch "^/$" "https://xxxx.gogo.in/Websiteapp/"
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

  </VirtualHost>

<IfModule manager_module>

 ManagerBalancerName other-server-group


        <VirtualHost myappcluster:7777>
         # <Directory />
         #   Order deny,allow
         #   Deny from all
         #   Allow from 172.158.50.
         # </Directory>

          <Location /mcm>
            SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 172.158.50.
          </Location>

          EnableMCPMReceive
          ProxyPass /Websiteapp/ balancer://other-server-group/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
          ProxyPassReverse /Websiteapp/ balancer://other-server-group/
          ProxyTimeout 180

         AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23364
         ServerAdvertise on http://172.158.50.9:7777

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Also my netstat command returns nothing.. We are unable to figure out what is the issue and why the httpd is unable to start..

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :443
```

Please assist. The configurations have been working since the last 2 years however we recently restarted the system and since then we are facing this error.

Error: (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 172.158.50.9:443

Comment: Is `172.158.50.9` actually a configured IP-address on your system ? Check with `ip addr`

Comment: @HBruijn Its actually a virtual IP which we use for pcs high availability.

Comment: @HBruijn Also I tried commenting the Listen related to *.9 and start the httpd. Its still giving the same error for *.122 which is part of ip addr and is the IP of the server where this config resides.

Comment: Do you really need to bind to a specific IP instead of INADDR_ANY?